# Why is "both of the most" grammatically wrong?

Tags: word-choice

If I said like "A and B are both of the smartest in our school", would that be grammatically wrong, because that implies "A is the smartest and B is the smartest either, so both are the 1st place at the same time"?

Answer (score 1):

The word **of** in **of the smartest** means that **the smartest** is to be understood as a *set* or a group.

{the smartest ones}

If those two people are in the set, you can say:

> They are **two** *of the smartest*.

The two of them belong to that set or group.

The phrase **both** means that they have something in common:

> They are both among the smartest..

What is it that they have in common? Each of them is **one of the smartest**. Each belongs to that group.

If they have a friend who is also one of the smartest:

> They are **three** of the smartest.

They are three members of the set {the smartest}.

The phrase **both of the smartest** is not idiomatic, though it is grammatical, and it would imply that the set, the smartest, contained only two members.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph: the natural way to say this would be "both of the two smartest". For example: "**Both of the two smartest** students in our school are graduating this year."

Comment: @TomChurch That is correct.

Comment: If one or *both of the two smartest* students were shortlisted...:)

Comment: Why would you say "Both of the two smartest...are...." when "The two smartest...are..." means exactly the same thing? The longer version does not sound natural at all, despite @TomChurch finding it so.